# Application releasing in Update/Upgrade mode with SQLite databse file update

Tags: android, sqlite, mode

I have developed an android app that accesses local sqlite database inside the app.

I have a question of how to upgrade the app. In this case, say if an application source code changes OR the database data/structure changes, how do I package these changes?

do i have to repackage complete app and make it available as a new app version ? or can I just package only the changed files into a much smaller build size and push it to market ?

In general, how is the application upgrade/update process carried out ?

Comment: repackage ... why? someone could just download only new version ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` (you should be), its constructor takes a version parameter, which is an integer value you should define in a constant like `DATABASE_VERSION` somewhere.

Override the `onUpgrade` method and implement the logic for upgrading your schema and/or data.

When you increment the `DATABASE_VERSION` constant (in an app update for instance), any existing installs that have a lower version will fire the code in `onUpgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Change DATABASE_VERSION of your db and next time you will start the app 
the db will be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

For both, you basically just export a new version of your application from Eclipse, and upload the new APK through your market account.

Application version changes are handled by a tag in the manifest: `android:versionCode`. Each time you export a updated APK, you need to increment the version code. `versionName` is just the label that's displayed to users in the market, so can be whatever you like.

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.package"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="17"
    android:versionName="0.74">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    ...
```

As for the database, the easiest way to do it is to sub-class [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Then, in your sub-class you can have something like this:

```
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 45;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    ...
```

The SQLiteOpenHelper handles opening the database, and updates when the application launches. In the above example, the database version is 45. If you increment that, and upload a new APK to the market, an `onUpgrade()` method is called, which allows you to update users old databases to your new version.